# Несогласованное определение или присловное дополнение?

Tags: грамматика

«Он раскрыл отчёт о предстоящей работе правительства.»

*О работе* — каким членом является данная фраза? Это несогласованное определение или присловное дополнение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Речь не идёт об"уклончивых"ответах, как выразилась уважаемая  Sibylla, речь о синкретичности - и тот, и другой ответ будет верен в школе,оба вопроса возможны(отчёт какой? отчёт о чём?). Если Вы учитесь в вузе, придётся разбираться подробнее и глубже.

Во-первых, с точки зрения синтаксиса. Если бы словоформа входила в состав подлежащего, это было бы точно определение, но в данном случае это состав сказуемого.

У нас дополнение, выражающее **объект действия**,такое дополнение употребляется при глаголах, а также при образованных от них сущ-х : Отчёт (о чём?)о работе(отчитываться о чём?о работе). Работа над чем? над докладом (работать (над чем?)над докладом) .

Другие дополнения, выражающие объект, на который распространяется качественный признак, употребляются при прилагательных и образованных от них сущ-х (верный(чему?)долгу).

Теперь **об определении.**

Наиболее частотными формами и значениями несогласованных определений являются следующие, учитывающие значение,способ выражения:

1. Принадлежность   Существительное в родительном падеже    Альбом сестры (ср.: альбом принадлежит сестре),книга брата (ср.: книга принадлежит брату).
2. Носитель признака    Существительное в родительном падеже    Зелень парков (ср.: парки зелены), белизна снега(ср.:снег белый).
3. Содержание определяемого понятия Существительное в родительном падеже    Правила поведения; политика мира.
   Существительное в предложном падеже с предлогом о (об)  Вопрос о наследстве; книга об открытиях.
   Инфинитив   Страсть противоречить; желание учиться.
4. Производитель действия   Существительное в родительном падеже    Пение птиц (ср.: птицы поют); открытие Колумба(ср.:Колумб открыл).
5. Качественная характеристика предмета (черта, свойство, возраст, мера, количество, признак по положению в пространстве)   Цельное словосочетание в родительном падеже Человек большого ума; человек высокого роста; девочка трёх лет.
   Существительное в винительном падеже с предлогом в  Платье в горошек; галстук в искорку.
   Существительное в творительном падеже с предлогом с Дом с мезонином; лодка с парусом.
   Существительное в предложном падеже с предлогом в   Дама в шляпе; человек в очках; озеро в лесу.
   Наречие Надпись по-английски; яйцо всмятку; глаза навыкате.
6. Материал Существительное в родительном падеже с предлогом из Дом из камня; платье из ситца; ваза из хрусталя.
7. Происхождение    Существительное в родительном падеже с предлогом из Генерал из солдат; староста из мужиков.
8. Вещество, содержащееся в предмете    Существительное в родительном падеже с предлогом из-под Бутылка из-под молока; банка из-под крема.
9. Источник Существительное в родительном падеже с предлогом от Пояс от платья; воронка от снаряда.
   Содержание определяемого понятия    Существительное в родительном падеже    Правила поведения; политика мира.

Нам подходит пункт 3: Существительное в предложном падеже с предлогом о (об)    Вопрос о наследстве; (вопрошать о наследстве); песня о Родине (петь о Родине); отчёт о работе (отчитываться о работе). Но сразу видно, что наш отчёт-отчитываться более связан с глагольностью главного слова в словосочетании, чем в предыдущих примерах.

Следовательно, **доминирует** функция объекта и синтаксическое значение **дополнения**, а *значение определения вторично.*

Так что при разборе подчёркиваем как дополнение, а как определение - под ним, то есть двойное подчёркивание, если в школе, а вот в вузе - только дополнение,но можно оговориться "с оттенком определения".

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила. Сомневаюсь, потому что в обоих случаях существительное может быть выражено в родительном падеже с предлогом о/об. Ну а с другой стороны, отчет какой - ***предстоящей  работе***. Т. е. получается сразу два определения - соглосованное и несоглосованное.

Answer (score 1):

Он раскрыл отчёт **о предстоящей работе правительства.**

**Это "вечный" вопрос с уклончивыми ответами, который задается постоянно.

**Вариант ответа**

1) Падежную форму можно считать **(1) дополнением или (2) определительным дополнением/объектным определением.**

Согласно определению, на дополнение должно распространяться действие (или проявляться признак). Здесь дополнением является существительное "отчёт".

**Примечание: Допускается считать дополнением падежные формы**, которые соответствуют объекту в соотносительных предложениях с глагольным управлением: отчитаться о  работе - отчёт о работе.

2) Почему не определение (несогласованное)?

Это связано с выбором  **более естественного** вопроса ("о чем", а не "какой"): Отчет (о чём) о работе правительства. Поэтому падежную форму можно считать **объектным определением,** которое отвечает на падежный вопрос.

Comment: Sibylla,Вы себе противоречите или ошиблись.Это не объектное определение, а объектное дополнение

Comment: Людмила,  а  термин "объектное дополнение" вроде бы смысла не имеет, классическое дополнение, отнесенное к глаголу,  - это и есть обычное объектное дополнение. Здесь же речь идет о совмещение двух функций - дополнения и определения, в терминологии это называется определительным дополнением или объектным определением (можно выбрать любое название).

Comment: Дополнение, конечно, всегда объектное, так что нет смысла его добавлять. Вызвала сомнение фраза:Почему не определение (несогласованное)? А потом идёт доказательство(основанное только на субъективном мнении о вопросе),что это объектное определение.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю еще раз и предлагаю для желающих **простую и однозначную картинку**, которая к тому же позволит **не изучать списки и не искать в них пункты**.

Сравним наше предложение **с пьесо**й, чтобы было интереснее и понятнее. Выделим в этой "пьесе" **четыре роли**: **подлежащее** (субъект действия), **сказуемое** (действие или процессуальный признак), **дополнение** (объект, на которое направлено действие) и **обстоятельство**, при котором происходит действие (время, место, причина, цель и т.д.).

И наконец обратимся **к определению**, которое может относиться к подлежащему или дополнению. **Выделим три вида определений**: (1) простое определение (какой?), (2) объектное определение (какой? + падежные вопросы), (3) обстоятельственное определение (какой + обстоятельственные вопросы).

**Проверяем метод на заданном примере**: Он раскрыл отчёт о предстоящей работе правительства.

Подлежащее + сказуемое + дополнение + объектное определение "о работе", отнесенное к дополнению. Это объектное определение (или присловное дополнение) распространено обычным определением "предстоящей".

Вывод: вся сложность проблемы состоит в том, что у объектных и обстоятельственных определений   **синтаксическая функция определения, а вопросы падежные, как у дополнения, или обстоятельственные.**

Comment: Теперь Вы  утверждаете, что это определение с падежными вопросами, т.е. несогласованное? Да нет, это синкретичный член предложения - дополнение как объект действия с оттенком определения со значением содержания  предмета.

Comment: К сожалению, Вы абсолютно не поняли моей мысли, но при этом знаете, что именно я утверждаю. К примеру, для чего Вы указываете вид определения (несогласованное), о согласованных определениях здесь вообще нет речи, определяется роль только падежных форм.  Ваш подход по сути своей формален, годится для разборов, но не для понимания действительной функции слов. К примеру, вы называете дополнением  и действительный  объект действия в заданном предложении,  и присловный  распространитель этого объекта.

Comment: Поэтому мне не очень ясна цель ваших комментариев: они только затемняет ситуацию, а люди которые захотят что-то понять, спросят скорее у автора.

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ Граммы.ру**

Подробно на Вашем вопросе останавливаются авторы учебника: Распопов И.П., Ломов А.М. Основы русской грамматики. Воронеж, 1984 (С. 220-222).
Существует разные позиции по вопросу о том, как синтаксически оценивать слова, зависящие от существительных и выраженные существительными в падежных и предложно-падежных формах.
Ряд лингвистов исходит из того, что любая (предложно-)падежная форма существительного, зависящая от другого существительного, является определением (например, В.Г. Адмони). Смысловые отношения, устанавливающиеся между главным и зависимым словом при этом не принимаются во внимание.
Другие лингвисты учитывают смысловые отношения между существительными и в зависимости от этого оценивают (предложно-)падежную форму либо как дополнение, либо как определение. Если предложно-падежная форма имеет обстоятельственное значение ("поездка в горы" - "куда?"), то она рассматривается обычно как несогласованное определение.
При установлении смысловых отношений между существительными учитывается конкретный или абстрактный характер каждого из них, семантика падежа зависимого существительного, семантика предлога (если есть).

Исходя из этого,  Ваши примеры можно охарактеризовать следующим образом:
"отчет о предстоящей работе" - несогласованное определение (если речь идет о документе) или дополнение (если речь идет о действии, соотносится с "отчитываться о...");
"выставка собак" - дополнение (исходное сочетание "выставлять собак"),
но "лай собак" - несогласованное определение (из исходного сочетания "собаки лают").
"Правила поведения"; "политика мира" - несогласованное определение (главные слова не связаны с глаголами). Ср. также: "мирная политика".

С уважением

GRAMMA.RU