# Почему при разборе предложения определение и дополнение часто "конфликтуют" между собой?

Tags: грамматика, терминология, определения, члены-предложения, дополнение

Речь идет о формах **существительного в косвенных падежах**, которые могут быть дополнениями или определениями, так что возникает проблема их **различения**. Нужно ли их различать или это **необязательно**? Зависит ли наше решение от вида **предложения** и контекста, где обозначена реальная **ситуация**.

**[Из книги Литневской](https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p86https://)**

```
 Другая проблема — допустимость двойного подчёркивания отдельных членов 
 предложения. Известно, что некоторые слова в предложении допускают 
 трактовку как РАЗНЫЕ члены предложения. Комплекс 2 для разбора случаев 
 такого рода предлагает использовать ДВОЙНОЕ подчёркивание одно под 
 другим. Хоть и допустимое, такое подчёркивание тем не менее не является 
 общепринятым: желательно предлагать только ОДИН вариант трактовки каждого 
 члена предложения.
```

Итак, в этой теме желательное все-таки определиться однозначно, и тогда возникают следующие **ВОПРОСЫ.**

Как косвенное дополнение **"дополняет"** предмет, когда оно относится к **существительному**, например:  *книга автора, автор книги, занятие спортом, мысли о будущем.* Во многих случаях подходят **оба** вопроса: (какой?) и падежные вопросы.

Как несогласованное определение **"определяет"** предмет, когда оно относится к **существительному**, например: *листья клена, дом из камня, книга для записи.*  Такие определения иногда называют **дополнительными**.

Меня интересуют не различные методики, а именно **суть проблемы** в дословном варианте: когда мы делаем наше суждение "полнее" (дополнение),  а когда что-то делим (определение). Можно рассказать историю лингвистических **терминов** (этимологию, происхождение).

Спасибо.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Для примера предлагаю сравнить два предложения:

(1) ***Листья клена** уже пожелтели, а у березок все еще зеленые.*

(2) *Для коллекции нужно собрать еще **листья клена** и рябины.*

Может ли падежная форма ***клена***  в сочетании ***листья клена*** быть определением или дополнением в **разных** предложениях? Если да, то почему?

Comment: Шарон, все зависит о контекста. Я уже отвечал на этот вопрос. Если смогу найти, дам ссылку.

Comment: Хорошо, найдите. А я пока полистала историю изучения второстепенных членов, различные направления (классические и современные). Но это надо разбираться. Посмотрела в поиске эту тему, нашла несколько конкретных вопросов  и почитала ответы.  Это просто театр!  Столько споров, у меня очень забавные ответы (даже про валентность есть). Развлекала я вас постоянно) Но вот про контекст что-то никто не говорил. А сейчас  я бы  это обязательно учитывала. Так называемый синкретизм должен преодолеваться именно в конкретике.

Comment: Шарон, вы отвечали на этот вопрос. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430399/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5

Comment: Я задавал этот вопрос Грамме. ру. Где мне его опубликовать? Здесь или там?

Comment: Да,  я это смотрела, вечные споры))  Хочется что-нибудь предельно ясного: посмотрел и сразу определил.  К тому же давно это было (целая вечность), наверное, я теперь думаю по-другому. Лучше здесь опубликуйте ответ, там и так много разговоров.  А я завтра посмотрю.

Comment: Я спрашиваю, потому что тема касается того вопроса. Некоторые могут не понять суть ответа. Ладно, и там и здесь опубликую..

Comment: Кстати, вы не знаете, почему Людмила больше не отвечает? Нет и других старых участников.

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ Граммы.ру.**

Подробно на Вашем вопросе останавливаются авторы учебника: Распопов И.П., Ломов А.М. Основы русской грамматики. Воронеж, 1984 (С. 220-222).
Существует разные позиции по вопросу о том, как синтаксически оценивать слова, зависящие от существительных и выраженные существительными в падежных и предложно-падежных формах.
Ряд лингвистов исходит из того, что любая (предложно-)падежная форма существительного, зависящая от другого существительного, является определением (например, В.Г. Адмони). Смысловые отношения, устанавливающиеся между главным и зависимым словом при этом не принимаются во внимание.
Другие лингвисты учитывают смысловые отношения между существительными и в зависимости от этого оценивают (предложно-)падежную форму либо как дополнение, либо как определение. Если предложно-падежная форма имеет обстоятельственное значение ("поездка в горы" - "куда?"), то она рассматривается обычно как несогласованное определение.
При установлении смысловых отношений между существительными учитывается конкретный или абстрактный характер каждого из них, семантика падежа зависимого существительного, семантика предлога (если есть).

Исходя из этого,  Ваши примеры можно охарактеризовать следующим образом:
"отчет о предстоящей работе" - несогласованное определение (если речь идет о документе) или дополнение (если речь идет о действии, соотносится с "отчитываться о...");
"выставка собак" - дополнение (исходное сочетание "выставлять собак"),
но "лай собак" - несогласованное определение (из исходного сочетания "собаки лают").
"Правила поведения"; "политика мира" - несогласованное определение (главные слова не связаны с глаголами). Ср. также: "мирная политика".

Вопрос, на который был дан этот ответ,см. [Несогласованное определение или присловное дополнение?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430399/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, прочитала я ответ, но яснее не стало.  Нужна ситуация, ее надо изобразить конкретно. А они говорят о непонятном "если". Нужен контекст: то ли персонаж документы по очереди читает, то ли его предстоящая работа сильно  заинтересовала.  //  А вы про мои листики клена можете что-нибудь сказать? У меня как раз ситуация обозначена.  Свой ответ по теме я позже дам.

Comment: Я отвечу позже..Обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Из истории изучения второстепенных членов предложения**

Учение о второстепенных членах развивалось в отечественной лингвистике **сложно и неоднозначно.**

```
В грамматиках вплоть до начала XIX века синтаксис сводился в 
основном к указанию на правила связи слов в предложении. 
Никакой классификации членов предложения по их 
синтаксической функции М.В. Ломоносов не дает. Тем не менее 
именно в его «Российской грамматике» впервые появляется 
термин **«обстоятельство».** В работах Н.И. Греча (1827) и  
А.Х. Востокова («1831 г.) впервые названы термины 
«определение» и «дополнение».В то же время существовал 
период, когда в 30-е годы XX века собирались отказаться   
совсем от терминов «дополнение», «определение», 
«обстоятельство». 
Условно в истории развития учения о второстепенных членах 
выделяют **два этапа**: 1) период классического, 
традиционного учения (30-е годы XIX века - 60-е годы XX 
века); 2) современная теория (с начала 60-х годов XX века). 
В современных исследованиях плодотворным признается 
структурно-семантический подход, учитывая то, что семантический 
принцип анализа сейчас весьма востребован в лингвистике.
```

2.**В школьной практике** изучение второстепенных членов предложения занимает важное место, и особо сложным является различение определений и дополнений, выраженных **падежными формами**.  Повторю еще раз свой материал из [предыдущего ответа](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430399/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

```
Сравним наше предложение с пьесой, чтобы было интереснее и 
понятнее. Выделим в этой "пьесе" четыре роли: подлежащее 
(субъект действия), сказуемое (действие или процессуальный 
признак), дополнение (объект, на которое направлено 
действие) и обстоятельство, при котором происходит действие 
(время, место, причина, цель и т.д.).
И наконец обратимся к определению, которое может относиться 
к подлежащему или дополнению. Выделим три вида определений: 
(1) простое определение (какой?), (2) объектное определение 
(какой? + падежные вопросы), (3) обстоятельственное 
 определение (какой + обстоятельственные вопросы).
```

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧ**

**Задача 1**

(1) *Для коллекции нужно собрать еще **листья (какие?)** клена и рябины.*

(2) *Листья **(чего?) клена** уже пожелтели, а у березки все еще зеленые.*

Итак, листья (какие? и чего?). Попробуем обойтись **без синкретизма.**

**В первом** предложении у нас определение. Почему? В коллекцию нужны (какие?) разные листья (от **разных** деревьев). Определение выступает в роли **классификатора**: кленовые, березовые и другие.  Выбор предмета **из ряда** других предметов по признаку/определению.

**Во втором** предложении мы наблюдаем за **конкретными** деревьями: кленом и березой. Здесь листья рассматриваются как часть дерева, значение **принадлежности** (лист этого клена и лист этой березы), поэтому это дополнение. Дополнение **дополняет** (раскрывает) содержание предмета.

**Задача 2**

Попробуем решить задачу с отчетом: *Он раскрыл отчёт **о предстоящей работе правительства.***

Все зависит от **контекста**. Если надо просмотреть **несколько** отчетов, то отчет (какой?) **определение.** Это **выбор** нужного предмета по признаку/определению.

Если нужно ознакомиться **с предстоящей  работой**, то нужны материалы по теме. Соответственно, надо просмотреть отчёт (о чем?) о предстоящей работе. Это **дополнение.**  Дополнение дополняет (раскрывает)  **содержание** предмета.

Comment: Шарон, ну ведь Грамма ответила. Отчёт о предстоящей работе — дополнение, если соотносится с действием, и определение — если речь идёт о документе.

Comment: Что касается ваших примеров. Да, согласен с вами. В первом предложении — это определение, во втором — дополнение.

Comment: Грамма дает общие указания, не более того. Вот был задан вопрос.  Участники отвечают кто как, но во всех ответах синкретизм присутствует. Я же считаю,  что  решить эту  задачу можно только по контексту, а без  него  решение вообще не имеет смысла.  Мне кажется, мало кто понял, какую методику я предлагаю. Ну да ладно. Тем не менее в дальнейшем я постараюсь давать на такие вопросы однозначные ответы.

Comment: Ну ведь и Грамма пишет: При установлении смысловых отношений между существительными учитывается конкретный или абстрактный характер каждого из них, семантика падежа зависимого существительного, семантика предлога (если есть). Т. е. все зависит от контекста. Так и вашем случае: зависимая словоформа стоит после после глагола и относится к нему.

Comment: Ну да, всё учитывается, а то как же! А как до конкретики дойдет, то все учитывают по-разному, а доказать друг другу ничего не могут.  Это как с факультативным обособлением обстоятельств: факторов много, а вывод должен быть один: как писать-то? (Я по интонации решаю,  а про остальных не знаю.) И здесь то же самое, одним словом –  "синкретизм непреодолимый".  А я люблю однозначные решения, Вот и Литневская велит одной чертой подчеркивать, а не двумя.

Comment: А что написано у Кустовой?

Comment: Да много чего написано, но она дает информацию в общем виде. Про синкретизм просто указывает, но конкретные задачи не решает.

Comment: Я ведь не зря  так ставлю вопрос:   Меня интересуют не различные методики, а именно суть проблемы в дословном варианте: когда мы делаем наше суждение "полнее" (дополнение), а когда что-то делим (определение).  Особенно "определение" интересно: что мы "делим"?  Каково происхождение термина?

Comment: У меня есть книга об учении членов предложения. Если что найду — напишу.

Comment: Спасибо. Целая книга?  А вы не можете коротко сказать, что в ней говорится по нашей теме. Основную идею: как преодолеть синкретизм?

Comment: Шарон, там про синкретизм вряд ли будет написано. Там о возникновении частей речи в целом написано.

Comment: Спасибо. Это тоже интересно.